# PHP include and database connection

Tags: php, include

In my PHP codes, I always have this problem that I can not use include somewhere!

For e.g. I'm using MySQL to connect to my database and I made a global.php to include & connect to my database and use it for all other PHP files.

But somewhere I keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connect() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\mypm\functions\global.php:4) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mypm\functions\global.php on line 7
```

I can not include or use some files that uses global.php in other PHP files!

Any suggestions? Thanks

Here is the code

```
require ('users.php'); function get_gravatar($id) { $email = get_email($id); $s = 80; $d = 'mm'; $r = 'g'; $img = false; $atts = array();
$url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'; $url .= md5( strtolower( trim($email) ) ); 
$url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
    if ( $img ) {
       $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"'; foreach ( $atts as $key => $val ) $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"'; $url .= ' />'; } return $url; 
    }
```

Comment: `require_once ('users.php');
function get_gravatar($id) {

$email = get_email($id);
$s = 80; $d = 'mm'; $r = 'g'; $img = false; $atts = array();
     $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
     $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
     $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
     if ( $img ) {
         $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
         foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
             $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
         $url .= ' />';
     }
     return $url;
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has alternate versions of `include()` and `require()` which address this problem.  Use `include_once()` or `require_once()` for files which might be included from multiple files to prevent the common file from being included in your code multiple times.

Comment: to keep a file such as `config.php` from being included more then once, you need to make sure that *every single* `include "config.php"` is changed to `include_once "config.php"`

Answer (score 3):

you need to do:

```
include_once 'global.php';
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score 1):

You can not do `include "db.php";` you must type `require_once "db.php";`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us code. Unless we wont able to look into the issue. You might be, including the same file twice, in the same code by mistake. Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one php file loading on the page?

The variable is defined more than once